# Sublime text + Anaconda выдает ошибку в документировании функции Python

Tags: python, sublime-text-3, anaconda

Как исправить эту ошибку?

Все видно на скрине:
[image]

Comment: какую ошибку? судя по коду на скриншоте интерпретатор должен выбросить `IndentationError`, а у вас в консоли TypeError, сделайте отступ для комментария внутри функции и ошибки не будет.

Comment: @borisrozumnuk Спасибо, но, боюсь, ошибка никуда не делась, в консоли ничего не пишет, но комментарии все равно подсвечивает